# Collide RealityKit 3D model with LiDAR mesh

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I spent many days trying to understand and follow examples without success.
My goal is to place a virtual AR object to the real world scanned previously with the LiDAR. With the `showSceneUnderstanding` I can see the realtime mesh created ok that fine.
With a tap function I can insert a usdz file, that also fine.
Because I have `toyModel.physicsBody?.mode = .kinematic` and `self.arView.installGestures(for: toyRobot)` I can move/scale the model.
Now want to be able move the model AND collide with the mesh generated by the LiDAR. When I move the model to a scanned wall the mesh it's stopped for example.

Here is my complete code :

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.arView.session.delegate = self
        
        //Scene Understanding options
        self.arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert([.physics, .collision, .occlusion])
        
        //Only for dev
        self.arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
        
        self.tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(placeObject(_:)))
        self.arView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapRecognizer)
        
    }
    
    @objc func placeObject(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // Perform a ray cast against the mesh (sceneUnderstanding)
        // Note: Ray-cast option ".estimatedPlane" with alignment ".any" also takes the mesh into account.
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
        if let result = arView.raycast(from: tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first {
            
            // Load the "Toy robot"
            let toyRobot = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: "toy_robot_vintage.usdz")
                
            // Add gestures to the toy (only available is physicsBody mode == kinematic)
            self.arView.installGestures(for: toyRobot)
            
            // Toy Anchor to place the toy on surface
            let toyAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
                toyAnchor.addChild(toyRobot)
            
            // Create a "Physics" model of the toy in order to add physics mode
            guard let toyModel = toyAnchor.children.first as? HasPhysics else {
                return
            }
            
            // Because toyModel is a fresh new model we need to init physics
            toyModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            toyModel.physicsBody = .init()
            
            // Add the physics body mode
            toyModel.physicsBody?.mode = .kinematic
            
            let test = ShapeResource.generateConvex(from: toyRobot.model!.mesh)
            
            toyModel.components[CollisionComponent] = CollisionComponent(shapes: [test], mode: .default, filter: .default)
            
            // Finally add the toy anchor to the scene
            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(toyAnchor)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Someone knows if it's possible to achieve that ? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @AndyFedoroff thanks for your reply. I mean if anymore knows how to stops the AR 3D model when I drag it to a wall for example, scanned by the lidar.

Comment: @AndyFedoroff yes exactly!!

Comment: @AndyFedoroff do you have maybe an idea ;-) ? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Whaooo super!! Can't wait for your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Following the previous discussion with @AndyFedoroff I added convext raycast in order, always, to collide the placed 3d object with the LiDAR created mesh. Here is my full code. I don't know if I'm doing well... In any case still doesn't work.

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    var panGestureEntity: Entity? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.arView.session.delegate = self
        
        //Scene Understanding options
        self.arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert([.physics, .collision, .occlusion])
        
        //Only for dev
        self.arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
        
        self.tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.placeObject))
        self.arView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapRecognizer)
        
        self.panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didPan))
        self.arView.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func placeObject(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // Perform a ray cast against the mesh (sceneUnderstanding)
        // Note: Ray-cast option ".estimatedPlane" with alignment ".any" also takes the mesh into account.
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: arView)
        if let result = self.arView.raycast(from: tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any).first {

            // Load the "Toy robot"
            let toyRobot = try! ModelEntity.loadModel(named: "toy_robot_vintage.usdz")

            // Add gestures to the toy (only available is physicsBody mode == kinematic)
            self.arView.installGestures(for: toyRobot)

            // Toy Anchor to place the toy on surface
            let toyAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: result.worldTransform)
                toyAnchor.addChild(toyRobot)

            // Create a "Physics" model of the toy in order to add physics mode
            guard let model = toyAnchor.children.first as? (Entity & HasPhysics)
            else { return }

            model.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            model.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: [.generateBox(size: .one)],
                                                       mass: 1.0,
                                                   material: .default,
                                                   mode: .kinematic)

            // Finally add the toy anchor to the scene
            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(toyAnchor)
            
        }
    
    }
    
    @objc public func didPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        print(sender.state)
        let point = sender.location(in: self.arView)
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            if let entity = self.arView.hitTest(point).first?.entity {
                self.panGestureEntity = entity
            } else {
                self.panGestureEntity = nil
            }
        case .changed:
            if let entity = self.panGestureEntity {
                if let raycast = arView
                    .scene
                    .raycast(origin: .zero, direction: .one, length: 1, query: .all, mask: .all, relativeTo: entity)
                    .first
                {
                    print("hit", raycast.entity, raycast.distance)
                }

          }
        case .ended:
            self.panGestureEntity = nil
        default: break;
        }

    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downcasting to `Entity & HasPhysics`:

```
guard let model = anchor.children.first as? (Entity & HasPhysics) 
else { return }

model.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
model.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: [.generateBox(size: .one)],
                                           mass: 1.0, 
                                       material: .default, 
                                           mode: .kinematic)
```

Official documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/3244071-generatecollisionshapes):

> ***For non-model entities***, `generateCollisionShapes(recursive:)` method has no effect. Nevertheless, the method is defined for all entities so that you can call it on any entity, and have the calculation propagate recursively to all that entity’s descendants.

Comment: Hi @AndyFedoroff thanks for your reply. Here is my updated code containing your solution: https://gist.github.com/MickaelCruzDB/047c13a432d8b6981489a9b6aee42732 Unfortunately the 3d model can cross walls, and all obstacles created by the Lidar mesh..

Comment: Moreover I can not force the downcast without this error : Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Entity & HasPhysics'

Comment: I found your answer in this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393887/how-to-detect-penetration-without-physical-interaction-in-arkit maybe convex ray cast could be an idea.. What do you think ?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to use raycast. Pity but I can't test it because at the moment I have no device with LiDAR...

Comment: No issue but could you help me with the code? I do not understand how to implement convext raycast with my actual code? Thanks again!!